# Wood sag question

Tags: safety, wood-selection, strength, framing, wood-properties

I used a 2ft. piece of 2x12 Doug Fir as a small ramp for truck.

When truck weight was on the 2x12; the 2x12 flexed (sagged) a little and when the weight was removed the 2x12 went back into its regular straightness.

The wood made a little popping sounds but there are no cracks or anything.

I’m curious as to is this wood still strong in both planes or did the momentary sagging under weight  greatly reduce the strength of the the wood?

Comment: If you heard sounds from the board there's every chance that it fractured slightly. There's no way of telling whether its strength has been compromised by a lot or a little, sorry. I think you should assume it isn't as strong as it was, just to be on the safe side. There's a simple solution to any worries about strength here however and that's to add triangles of solid wood or stout plywood under the piece of 2x12.

Comment: @Graphus  I am a little confused by your comment re triangles.  are they parallel or perpendicular? How large?  How attached?

Comment: @Ashlar, all could be clarified *if* the OP comes back.